# easier way to get value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with a structure like:

```
array = [
    { id: 1001 , info: {bunch of info in here} },
    { id: 1002 , info: {bunch of info in here} }
]
```

is there a way I can grab all the info of id = 1002 without having to loop through the array with .each()?

Comment: Define 'grab'. To do what with it? In what format? Etc.

Comment: No you cannot but anyway that's not the answer you got from your quite similar previous question asked few minutes ago...

Comment: You may look at lo-dash

Comment: Why without using `.each`? Why not just use it?

Comment: I save information in an array like this. later on I need the value of 'info' to display it to users, eg: var info = array[0].info, company = info.company, address = info.address etc. My problem is I want to be able to do something like : array[id] to get the info rather than have to know the index

Comment: So use an object not an array!

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can pre-process:

```
var map = {};
array.forEach(function(item) {map[item.id] = item.info;});
```

Then you can access properties by ID much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

In case possible, chnage your array to map, where the key will be ID value and value will be Info.

Something like:

```
array[1002] = [
    { id: 1002 , info: {bunch of info in here} }
]
array[1001] = [
    { id: 1001 , info: {bunch of info in here} }
]
```

Comment: array is ordered list, creating an entry with specific index will generate undefined slot in array memory, meaning if setting on empty array an index of 1001, it will create an array with one entry defined but with a length of 1002 elements. I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/Chpb8/  Not really great...

Answer (score 0):

I know the tags are Javascript and Jquery only but have a look at underscorejs. It has a lot of useful stuff to work with array. Fo example [where](http://underscorejs.org/#where) function from underscorejs would give you what you are actually trying to achive.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But that internally will loop throught all the array entries

Comment: @Wolff very true, but he is looking for an easier way to do it without each statement so I thought performance is not important here